# Log SQL Statements from JdbcTemplate or SimpleJdbcTemplate via AOP

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, aop

I am trying to log executed SQL queries in spring JdbcTemplate and SimpleJdbcTemplate using aspect oriented programming. I have copy-pasted code from this [tutorial](http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/java-programming/log-sql-statements-with-parameter-values-filled-in-spring-jdbc/)

Pointcut defined as

```java
@Before(
    "execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations.*(String, ..))"
)
```

works great for intercepting JdbcTemplate queries. But when i changed pointcut to

```java
@Before(
    "execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations.*(String, ..)) throws *Exception || " +
    "execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcOperations.*(String, ..)) throws *Exception"
)
```

or

```java
@Before(
    "execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations.*(String, ..)) || " +
    "execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcOperations.*(String, ..))"
)
```

then only JdbcTemplate queries were intercepted without SimpleJdbcTemplate 
queries.

Any hints how to intercept queries from SimpleJdbcTemplate via AOP while preserving loging queries from JdbcTemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an AspectJ user I can say that your pointcuts look okay. As a non-Spring user I can only speculate that

- maybe your code does not use `SimpleJdbcOperations` at all or
- maybe Spring itself does not even though you expect it to, possibly because the interface is actually [deprecated since Spring 3.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcOperations.html).

BTW, just for the fun of it I have an idea for you about how you can actually shorten your pointcuts a bit if you do not mind also capturing `NamedParameterJdbcOperations`:

```java
@Before("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core..*JdbcOperations.*(String, ..))")
```